# Multiple vendor Support for Virtuemart 2.0.8 in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

How to provide **Multiple vendor Support for Virtuemart 2.0.8 in Joomla 2.5** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best method I have used is VM Vendor Component .
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-uploads/8239

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/marketplace-for-virtuemart

This extension support addition addons which extend the marketplace functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a commercial extension, I recommend Multi vendor virtuemart extension from Codingmall. It is a bit pricey but has a lot of features.

Check this 
http://codingmall.com/faq/7-joomla-products/151-virtuemart-multi-vendor-configuration-a-settings